# jQuery .on() not binding/refreshing correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my HTML, I have a div:

```
<div id='layerList'>

</div>
```

In my JavaScript, I dynamically append several items to this div, for example:

```
$('#layerList').append("<a class='lays dropdown-item' href='#'> This is an example </a>");
```

So far, everything works fine. My menu is built dynamically.

When I click on the different menu items, I want to change the active state and do other things, but it's not working — the menu items don't change state. Below is the click event handler:

```
$("#layerList").on("click", '.lays', function () {
    console.log("test") // this works, I can see it
    $(".lays").removeClass("active"); // this does not work
    $(this).addClass("active"); // this does not work 
    // other stuff, doesn't work
});
```

Note that this code works just fine if I add the menu items in my HTML (i.e., if I do not create them dynamically).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added a console.log to the handler to see that it executes?  Where is the binding in relation to the page?

Comment: You need to give more details. In what way is it not working? Is it exploding your computer? Is it throwing an error message?

Comment: Is it inside of a `$(document).ready(){...}`?

Comment: There are no error messages. The menu items simply don't change active states, and they are not clickable. However, the console.log() message is outputted.

Comment: Yes, it is inside $(document).ready(){}

Comment: Show us the css code for `.lays.active`

Comment: I don't apply any css

Comment: Problem found then, it *is* working; just not making a visual clue.

Comment: I am editing my question with additional details. Please see above.

Comment: Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vnwcamw/6/) Its working, you just don't see it.

Comment: Hmm, yes your jsfiddle works. So, must be something else in my code conflicting?? Not sure what.

Comment: Try that, add a css style to `.lays.active` and check if its not working...

Comment: It is a Bootstrap menu, so when I add/remove 'active', I should be able to see if it's working.

Comment: Also, change `console.log("test")` to `console.log("test", this)` and verify that `this` is the clicked `a` (It should be, unless you have misspelled a class name).

Comment: Exactly what bootstrap menu are you using?

Comment: I can verify that `this` works

Comment: The Bootstrap menu is `class="dropdown-menu"`

Comment: What jquery version do you load?

Comment: I fixed it!!! Basically, I had other code that was reversing the menu choice I made. Dumb error. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving the same effect.
**jQuery:**
You can achieve the same effect using the shorthand `.click` method on the jQuery prototype. Attaching the event listener to the document and filtering through children is slow and will keep *getting* slower as your page size increases. Let me show you the code I have used.

```js
$(".lays").click(function(e) {
  $(".lays")
    .removeClass("active");

  $(this)
    .addClass("active");
  // other stuff
  return false;
});
```

```css
.lays.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='layerList'>
  <a class='lays dropdown-item' href='#'> This is an example </a><br><a class='lays dropdown-item' href='#'> This is an example </a>
</div>
```

**Using the buit-in javascript DOM API:**
If you want a faster solution that does not need external libs, then accessing the DOM API might be better for you. The syntax is longer than jQuery's **and** doesn't have [method chaining](https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html)
so you'll end up with a bit more code than jQuery.

```js
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("lays")).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("lays")).forEach(function(element) {
      element.classList.remove("active");
    });

    element.classList.add("active");
    //other stuff
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.lays.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='layerList'>
  <a class='lays dropdown-item' href='#'> This is an example </a><br><a class='lays dropdown-item' href='#'> This is an example </a>
</div>
```

Using `[].slice.call` turns an [iterable object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) into an Array.
If you wanted to add support for older browsers, then I recommend adding a [polyfill for the `Array.from` method](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Array.from).

Anyway, the code does work, so I'm not sure what's happening on your computer. Have you tried using Incognito Mode or the Guest account on Chrome, or Safe Mode on Firefox? Check all your extensions, as it is working fine in my browser (Google Chrome) right now. Good luck to you! :)

Answer (score -1):

try a this way $("#layerList").on("click", 'a.lays', function () {

```
$("#layerList").on("click", 'a.lays', function () {
   $(".lays").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
   // other stuff
```

});

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I have no idea why. This should be working.

Comment: try again a.lays

Comment: His question has a less strict child selector.  Yours has a more strict selector.  If his less strict selector doesn't work, then there is another issue that making the selector more strict *will not* fix.

Comment: It logically could not work, as it's not addressing the real issue.